# I have created a PreparedStatement object and when I inspect that element I can see m_type=12. What is this m_type=12

Tags: java, prepared-statement

I have created a `PreparedStatement` object and I passed my SQL query to it.
After that I set 9 parameters to that `PreparesStatement` object by reading an array.

When I inspect the `PreparesStatement` object reference, I can see `m_type=12`. What is this `m_type=12`?

[image: 1]

Comment: Why do you care? This is something specific to the internals of the PostgreSQL JDBC driver implementation and/or the PostgreSQL wire protocol. To use a prepared statement you really do not need to know. And if you really need to know, you can find the source of the PostgreSQL JDBC driver at https://github.com/pgjdbc/pgjdbc, where you can find out what it does exactly.

Comment: In any case, given the name of the field, and the data type it is in, I guess it identifies the data type. It might be a PostgreSQL specific type code, or it might be the JDBC type code (`java.sql.Types.VARCHAR` has value 12 for example).

Comment: @MarkRotteveel I believe [`JDBCType`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.sql/java/sql/JDBCType.html) 12 is also VARCHAR. And the `m_value` looks like a `String` (an ISO-8601 date as a String)

Comment: @ElliottFrisch `java.sql.JDBCType` is an enum equivalent of `java.sql.Types`.

Comment: On SO, there is "This question does not show any research effort," but this is the seldom seen corollary, "This question shows TOO MUCH research effort."